# This Page Can't be Displayed - bKash payment api integration App URL access issue

Tags: laravel, api

We already developed a web application and integrate bKash API for payment and we validated from bKash 1st & 2nd sandbox testing. But Next they want to access our web application app url before going to live (The app URL need to display the bKash payment popup when the user wants to pay with bKash). But they tell that they can't access our APP URL. But we can access our app URL with a link and add with img tag.

[Error or Problem Image Link - Click to see](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kp3iZF5FKCjNqopbcTWzYu7ric5ENy8r/view?usp=share_link)

Our application is developed with Laravel Framework and we already fixed cors access.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that bKash's firewall is blocking your website because of their firewall rules.

There's not much that can be done from your side. You will need to ask them to whitelist your website or ask them to connect to a VPN and then access your website.

Another alternative would be for you to host it on a different domain which has not yet been blocked by their firewall.

Comment: We already change 3 times our server where we deploy the application. But the problem is the problem.

Comment: @AbdulMajid your server is not the issue. bKash has blocked your domain ( example, mydomain.com ). Changing server's will most likely not do much, you need to ask them to whitelist your domain